# moment() function works in html but not in separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I have included moment.min.js in my page

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/fatcalc.js"></script>
```

I can call

```
<script>document.write(moment());</script>
```

and it displays the date fine on my page.

But, when I call it from within fatcalc.js

```
var date = moment();
```

I get the error:

> 'moment' is not defined.

Why can my html page see it, but not the fatcalc.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Seems to be some issue with Jshint I don't understand but adding this to the top  of my script fixed it.

```
/*global moment:true */
```